# Is it possible to use hover with multiple column background colors in kableExtra?

Tags: r, hover, kable

I want to specify column colors, but when I hover over them, to still be able to highlight a particular row. i.e., when hovering over a row the color changes.

In this example, the two columns with color do not change when hovering over. I would like them to change as well.

```
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
kable(mtcars, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  column_spec(2, color = "white",
              background = "#ADD8E6") %>%
  column_spec(3, color = "white",
              background = "#ADBCE6")
```

Comment: you want the color to change when you hover over it? Your question is not clear (to me). Please add detail.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I want the color to change when hovering over. I added more detail in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your Rmd file and the chosen color will appear when hovering over, like this:

````
---
title: "Sales - YtD 2020"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  runtime: shiny       
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

```

---
<style>
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover { 
  background-color: #f4f442;
}
</style>

Sales
=======================================================================

Row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Your dashboard output
````